# Django message + nginx: message showing after 3 times reload !! admin login redirects back to admin login page after giving right credentials

Tags: django, nginx, django-messages

I have built a Django application. It was working fine in the development mode. But I tried to host it in the digital ocean, Every thing worked fine, but when any error message is sent as a response, It doesn't show instantly in the front-end. Weirdly enough, If I reload three times, the error message becomes visible. my nginx configuration:

```
    listen 80;
    server_name <domain name>;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias  /home/saadman/<project name>/staticfiles/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;    
    }
}
```

my gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=saadman
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/saadman/<projectname>
ExecStart=/home/saadman/<projectname>/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          <projectname>.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Yes, the issue was, I was using a random key generator to produce Django secret key, so when it was deployed, 4 separate secret keys were generated for 4 gunicorn workers. So I fixed the Django secret key and set it to a constant value. And it worked